# Extract href from https site with accept/reject page to enter

Tags: java, http, jsoup, href, extract

On this site: https://services.cds.ca/applications/taxforms/taxforms.nsf/Pages/-EN-LimitedPartnershipsandIncomeTrusts?Open

If you click through on: Display tax information for year 2015, Click Accept, you will arrive at: https://services.cds.ca/applications/taxforms/taxforms.nsf/PROCESSED-EN-?OpenView&Start=1&Count=3000&RestrictToCategory=All-2015

The end goal is get all the excel file href's linked on this page.

Using the JSoup library, I have been able to read in HTML and find href's on a number of different websites, but encountering some issues when trying to apply it to this more complicated webpage.

If anyone could point me in the right direction for some reference material on what is hanging me up here or provide an example, it would be greatly appreciated.

Example code of what I had been using for other sites that does not seem to work for grabbing the HTML from this webpage is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class URLReader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/").get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a");
        for (Element e: links) { 
                System.out.println(e.attr("abs:href"));
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 
    }
}
}
```

However, when I throw the CDS url mentioned at the top in place for google, the program hangs at execution and eventually comes to a "Connection reset" catch error message.

Also, in the HTML of the CDS website linked above, I see some javascript:
if   (document.referrer.indexOf("/applications/taxforms/taxforms.nsf/Pages/-EN-agree?Open") <= 0 )       location.href = "/applications/taxforms/taxforms.nsf/Pages/-EN-agree?Open&OpenView&Start=1&Count=3000&RestrictToCategory=All-2015";
Which throws you back to the Accept/Reject disclaimer page that precedes entering this page. Wondering some form post or data passing is needed get me past this, if this is what is causing me the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code that you have tried and what are the issues you are facing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, example code added in original post now. Thanks.